# Socket.io + NodeJS + Nginx + SSL

Tags: node.js, sockets, ssl, nginx

My socket does not connect when I am using Nginx. My config file is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name mysite.com

    ssl     on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    ssl_protocols        TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'kEECDH+ECDSA+AES128 kEECDH+ECDSA+AES256 kEECDH+AES128 kEECDH+AES256 kEDH+AES128 kEDH+AES256 DES-CBC3-SHA +SHA !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !MD5 !EXP !DSS !PSK !SRP !kECDH !CAMELLIA !RC4 !SEED';

    ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    keepalive_timeout   70;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/dash.log;

    # pass the request to the node.js server
    location / {
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        add_header  Front-End-Https   on;

        proxy_pass         https://127.0.0.1:8081;
        proxy_redirect     off;

    }
}
```

My NodeJS is:

```
// Setup servers
var app = express();
var HTTPSOptions = {
    cert: fs.readFileSync(config.ssl.server_cert),
    key: fs.readFileSync(config.ssl.server_key),
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    passphrase: config.ssl.server_password
};
HTTPSOptions.agent = new https.Agent(HTTPSOptions);

io = io.listen(server, {
    log: false
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (sock) {
    console.log("CONNECTED");
});

var httpsServer = https.createServer(HTTPSOptions, app);
```

And my client is

```
var socket = io.connect('https://localhost',  {secure: true});
socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log("CONNECTED HERE TOO");
});
```

Needless to say, none of the two `console.log` show anything. I'm worried that nginx is blocking the request and node is actually never getting it?

Comment: Is there anything in the nginx logs? Did you make sure that calling localhost is actually matching mysite.com? any errors in the client console?

Comment: i have a quite similar problem....can you help me here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49210006/alexa-skill-server-socket-io-on-node-js-express-using-nginx-as-reverse-proxy

Comment: Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/62187296/268598

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there's missing `listen 443 ssl;`

Comment: i have a quite similar problem....can you help me here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49210006/alexa-skill-server-socket-io-on-node-js-express-using-nginx-as-reverse-proxy