# Bad Gateway Error using Socket.io Node.js over SSL

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, socket.io

I previously had a Socket.io script running fine over http, but upgrading to https has broken it. I have installed the cert on the server but no luck. The code for the server setup is:

```
var https = require('https'),
    fs =    require('fs');

var options = {
    key:    fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/ssl/default/54082/server.key'),
    cert:   fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/ssl/default/54082/server.crt')
};
var app = https.createServer(options);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
```

However in the web browser the page fails to connect to it and the console shows a `the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)` response.

Any ideas on if the script set up is wrong? Or perhaps something in the Nginx setup?

Many thanks

**Edit:** The front end code I'm using to connect:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://socket.example.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var io = io('https://socket.example.com', { secure: true });
</script>
```

**Edit::** Nginx config:

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/socket.example.co.uk/before/*;

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name socket.example.co.uk;
    root /home/forge/socket.example.co.uk;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/socket.example.co.uk/server/*;

    location / {    
        proxy_pass https://socket.example.co.uk:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}

# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/socket.example.co.uk/after/*;
```

Comment: Are you passing {secure: true} while connecting to server ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599470/node-js-socket-io-with-ssl

Comment: it is not necessary to proxy to node.js through nginx. the port is open, so connecting with `io.connect('<domain>:<port>',{secure:true});` from the client is all you need to do to get up and running. it is not possible to proxy through nginx (and not necessary since node binds to all interfaces, and the domain is routed to your ip:port anyway due to DNS config). i literally upgraded my socket io to https yesterday without problems.

Comment: @r3wt So you're saying the domain should be something different? What should it be? I am using the code `var io = io('https://socket.example.com/socketio/socketio.js', { secure: true });`

Comment: @MukeshSharma That isn't required as long as it a HTTPS url according to the docs. And it doesn't make a difference anyway.

Comment: i'm not saying that at all. just don't try and proxy to node.js with nginx. nginx will drop the connections every single time. you don't have to config anything on node.js or nginx, as long as node https server can read the valid cert and key for your domain name and its on the same box as node.js, it will work. the request will occur over ssl and end at the open port that your node.js process is using.

Comment: @r3wt So just add the code in my question and it should work? It doesn't work though. Are you saying I should get rid of Nginx? Any ideas anyone? :\

Comment: @r3wt :( No need for names. I'm trying my best and you don't have to help me. I'll post the front end code now...

Comment: the people who called me on my lack of effort are the ones who made me a better developer. instead of pardoning yourself for your incompetence, you should recognize this as a gift so that you can see the areas where you are deficient and need to improve in.

Comment: @r3wt I get it, I'm just not used to being called a swear word, but it's fine, thank you for your help. What effort am I not exerting, what else do I need to do? Happy to put in any effort needed - I've been working on this for 2 days.

Comment: you are not even suplying a port to connect with. why? your https server also isn't listening on any port?

Comment: @r2wt OK I will look into the port. It worked without a port just fine on http which is why I'm confused. I'll try adding a port.

Comment: Can you see are the ssl files are being read? Can you debug 'options' variable?, also tell me the command how are you lifting your application on server side?

Comment: Have you checked this one?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317831/socket-io-nodejs-nginx-ssl
Especially the part in location/ { } stating 'upgrade' ?

Comment: @CreasolDev Yes I have that line in my Nginx config.

Comment: @Sai That is in the question, do you need something else?

Comment: yes, may be those cert values are readable or not, since they are in /etc your app should have sudo permissions or something else. 502 bad gateway means nginx received an invalid response from the node application, also can you paste nginx configuration, it will be helpful to debug

Comment: @Sai Would the script run if they weren't readable? As the script is running and receiving events and outputting them on the command line as expected - it's just the front end that won't connect. Do you have any idea how I'd check if the certs were being read correctly?

Comment: @Sai I have added Nginx config

Comment: Even Im not sure, if it throws an error, but we too had a similar scenario( not socket.io but with express), we made nginx https while running the express on http, and configure. If you can paste nginx configuration, it will be helpful

Comment: I see it now, your proxy_pass is wrong, the moment you say https, your default port becomes 443, while you are running two things on same port one of the your node app would have got killed on your nginx won't read it. so what you can do is you can run the socket.io on http, since your nginx has https, it will take care of the encryption.

Comment: @Sai OK I will look into that. The reason I tried to set up HTTPS is that Chrome was refusing to load over HTTP citing security concerns. I will look into it further though...

Comment: @Sai Yeah the problem with this is that as the webpage is SSL, Chrome/Safari won't load the script over HTTP and the console gives a warning about refusing to load scripts over HTTP. Has to be SSL I guess.

Comment: You can try cors npm module for that problem accessing http over https. It worked for us.

Comment: I'll look into that module @Sai thank you. For now I have taken the coward's way out and am just using Pusher... Took about 15 minutes to set up!

Comment: Has this been solved? Looks like @samiles used a different solution, I am having the exact same problem however I do not have access to the server or the config files.

Answer (score 5):

1. make sure that your domain points to your server.
2. make sure that an nginx server block is running for your domain with ssl enabled.
3. remove any location blocks from your `nginx` config attempting to proxy to the port you are running your socket.io server on.
4. make sure your ssl certificate is valid.
5. connect with `io.connect()` instead of the way you are doing. leave out the protocol portion of the url (`https://`).
6. use `sudo killall -9 node` from the commandline to kill any zombie processes that might be lingering and bound to your port. this sometimes happens with socket.io when it fails to shutdown properly.

example from my own code:

```
var socket = io.connect('dev.somedomain.com:3000',{secure:true});
```

server example from my own domain:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    https = require('https'),
    config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config.json','utf-8')),
    serverOpts = {
        key: fs.readFileSync(config.server.key),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(config.server.cert)
    },
    server = https.createServer(serverOpts,function(req,res){}),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
   console.log('houston, we have lift off');
});

server.listen(config.port, function(){
    log('listening on *:%d',config.port);
});
```

obviously i'm reading the path to my certificate and key file from a config.json file but you should get the idea right?

Comment: Not had any luck with any of this. Thanks anyway for your help. Maybe there's something else in my setup somewhere breaking something... I'm just giving up now...

Answer (score 4):

The 502 (Bad Gateway) indicates that the nginx service tried to contact the proxy server but failed. The line in the nginx config

```
 proxy_pass https://socket.example.co.uk:3000;
```

seems to be the issue. Could not see from your nodejs code that the port 3000 is being used.

Answer (score -4):

I've same issue but with apache2, I solve it by add this line to my vhost config

`SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off`